# How to paint on the form through button click event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to figure out how to paint to the form using a button click event. I know the parameters needed for a paint event handler are `PaintEventArgs` and the button click event handler passes `EventArgs`

How can I get the form to paint by clicking a button? This is all being done in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: is this winforms? What do you mean by 'paint to the form'?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: But, i very much doubt you need the paint event

Comment: Yes it is for winforms. And I need to use paint because its within the realm of my classroom and that's what our professor used to paint the form

Comment: @kyleryan1291 So what is your specific problem at the moment? Do you want us to teach you how to draw tables? Please mark the answer below if it solved your problem. Based on the current information, your question is not specific enough, you can also edit and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example of paint on a form click:

```
void Main()
{
    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Show();
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        var colour = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        
        this.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            colour = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.Invalidate();
        };
        
        this.Paint += (s, e) =>
        {
            using var pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(colour);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 10, 20);
        };
    }
}
```

If the line changes from black to red on click then it works.

Comment: I appreciate this, but it has to be triggered through a button click and I cannot figure out how to acomplish that

Comment: @kyleryan1291 - This example is exactly doing that. The click triggers the paint through the `.Invalidate` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The button click event cannot initiate a paint event. Typically you tell the system the form needs repainting next time it can using the `.Invalidate()` method. The button click must change effect *what* to draw, but not *when* to draw it.

Below is a working example of how to draw on forms. Each time the button is pressed then a random point is added to the a list of points.

[image: fig1]

Then the system decides when to draw the form, and you can force a re-draw when possible after adding a new point in the list.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        readonly static Random rng = new Random();
        readonly List<Point> pointList;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pointList = new List<Point>();

            this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            // Connect points with lines
            if (pointList.Count >= 2)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, pointList.ToArray());
            }

            // Add a small square at each point
            foreach (var point in pointList)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                    point.X - 2, point.Y - 2, 4, 4);
            }
            
        }

        private void drawButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Adds a random point on the list
            pointList.Add(new Point(
                rng.Next(this.ClientSize.Width),
                rng.Next(this.ClientSize.Height)));

            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

PS. There is also `.Refresh()` which forces the re-draw immediately but this is generally not needed.

---

Well, to be exact you can, but you shouldn't. The code below would trigger and paint event instead of calling `.Invalidate()`

```
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    OnPaint(new PaintEventArgs(g, ClientRectangle));
```

The end effect is the same, except now you are messing with windows task scheduling and handling of the UI events.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not sure why my professor assigned us that then. The assignment was "Write a program that has 3 buttons. Pressing one of the button causes one of the three outputs below to be shown" and each output involves painting on the form. So I'm assuming the click event would trigger them to be displayed? I guess that's a different question

Comment: The second part you added is good to know

Comment: Each button should change some variables and call `Invalidate()`. Then the paint event does the drawing according to the state of the variables set by the buttons.